# How to disable auto-scrolling when using Window.find() inside an iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll

I have a search function that finds keywords inside an iFrame that looks like this:

```
const iWindow = iframe.contentWindow; 
iframe.contentDocument.designMode = "on"; //This is supposed to prevent scrolling but doesn't
while (iWindow.find(keyword)) {
    // Logic for found keyword handling here
}
iframe.contentDocument.designMode = "off";
```

The issue occurs when `iWindow.find(keyword)` is executed, for every match found the page will automatically scroll to it's location on the page.  This at times causes a scroll to the very bottom of the page if a match happens to be there.  I am using this same logic for elements not inside an iFrame and everything works smoothly with no scrolling as long as I include `document.designMode = "on"`.  For some reason setting `iframe.contentDocument.designMode = "on"` does not have the same scroll-lock effect.

Any suggestions on how to disable scrolling while the `iWindow.find()` is being performed?

Comment: Which browser you are testing on? `Window.find` isn't on any specification and browser might behave differently.

Comment: Currently testing on Chrome, but  `window.find` also works the same on Firefox, Edge, and IE

Comment: I keep getting "Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "find" on cross-origin object" when tried to use iWindow.find(keyword). Don't you get this error as well? note: I commented out designmode lines to try because iframe.contentDocument is null in FF

Comment: @chadb768 you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable scroll just before and re-enable it just after the whole while loop is done. Something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', noScroll);
// find logic
setTimeout(() => window.removeEventListener('scroll', noScroll), 500);
```

Where `noScroll` is your function that disables scrolling (something like `window.scrollTo(0,0)`). I've found useful adding the `setTimeout` in a script I was working on, otherwise the last event won'f fire. It may be useless in your case.